Is there a way to detect reflectively how a Java module has been patched?
In an implementation of the Java Platform Module System, as implemented by most OpenJDK implementations, you can patch a module with classes from other artifacts. (Maven does this during Surefire runs, as an arbitrary example, in certain situations, to make it look like classes under test-classes are also part of the module whose classes are under classes.)
From within a program running in such an environment, there appears to be no way to tell, reflectively, that this has happened to any given module, short of looking for some particular text in an undocumented toString() output. I assume that is at least partially by design, since patching is a property of an OpenJDK implementation, not of the OpenJDK itself. However it can be useful to know whether a given module has been patched, and, even better, with what.
So: other than examining the unspecified toString() output of ModuleReference, which will typically end with the text " (patched)", is there any other way to do this?
Is there any way to tell with what artifact a given module has been patched?
The best idea I can come up with, which is quite horrible, is to open a ModuleReader and use it to find() every resource, and then examine the URIs reachable from that operation to check for differences (i.e. basically reverse-engineer the patch).
Update: TIL about https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8156998, which suggests that in order to implement that, there must be some sort of path forward underneath everything to reconstruct the patch.

I'm not aware of any public API for this. Though to be fair, patching modules does not seem to be an inherent aspect of JPMS--it's basically an implementation detail. If you know the implementation will be jdk.internal.module.ModuleReferenceImpl then you can make use of isPatched(), though that requires you use --add-exports or --add-opens to use it.
